# loop unrolling with flex/bison

Tags: loops, for-loop, bison, lex

I'm writing a Flex/Bison parser for a language which contains for loop pre-processor directives, which should replicate loop content. Example:

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++)
    record$i = value$i;
endfor
```

my pre-processor should generate the following output

```
record0 = value0;
record1 = value1;
```

I need to support nested loops.
Can anyone suggest an idea how to implement this using Flex/Bison.

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Flex and bison are parsing tools.  So you could use them to parse your language into some internal form, and then you could evaluate that internal form to produce the output you want.  These are really two completely different tasks, related only by the internal form you choose to use (which could be just about anything -- what is best depends on what your language is, and what you want your pre-processor to do with it).

Overall your question is so broad that it defies any answer more detailed than just 'use flex and bison to parse your language, and use some sort of simple interpreter to evaluate the result'.  As to exactly how you do that, that's about 30 or 40 separate questions.

Comment: thanks for explanations. i'll do more homework... i'd want to see some code example, implementing similar task.